# Converting 4 sided cube into 3 side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a "3 photo cube" with cube effect rotating. 
Found a very helpful codepen which created the cube with 4 sides and did the rotating and stopping by side which was exactly what i wanted.

Issue here is that i need the cube to show just 3 sides not 4 and when i remove one of them, it still rotates on that side.

I thought i should just "match" top side bottom side so the back side doesn't show but it seems i am having a little knowledge at understanding how the positioning works.

see the below snippet.

```css
.scene {
  width: 416px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 75px auto 0;
  perspective: 1200px;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 416px;
  height: 500px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(0px) rotateX(150deg);
  animation: example 15s linear infinite;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 416px;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #999;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 120px 0;
  font: 50px/1 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
.side::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.side span {
  position: relative;
}

.guides {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 0 1px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.guides::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px dotted;
}

.back {
  transform: translateZ(-250px) rotateX(180deg);
}
.bottom {
  transform: translateY(250px) rotateX(270deg);
}
.front {
  transform: translateZ(250px);
}

.top {
  background-image: url(https://askd.github.io/codepen/top.jpg);
}
.back {
  background-image: url(http://keit.rezsolution.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/rimodelimi-i-hundes-galeri.jpg);
}
.bottom {
  background-image: url(http://keit.rezsolution.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/foto-galeri-zmadhimi-i-gjoksit.jpg);
}
.front {
  background-image: url(http://keit.rezsolution.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/barku-home.jpg);
}

@keyframes example {
  0% { transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateX(0deg); }
 15% { transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg); }
 25% { transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg); }
 40% { transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg); }
 50% { transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateX(180deg); }
 65% { transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateX(270deg); }
 75% { transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateX(270deg); }
 90% { transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateX(360deg); }
 100% { transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateX(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side back">
      <span>BACK</span>
    </div>
    <div class="side bottom">
      <span>BOTTOM</span>
    </div>
    <div class="side front">
      <span>FRONT</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anybody can give me some directions on how to approach this issue?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a working exemple of a rotating prism (Y axis) [here](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/MNEVrX).
And the same on the X axis [here](https://codepen.io/pi-L/pen/bXoJvx).
There are 2 things to figure out, the **distance to translate** each face and the **rotation angle**.
The distance bring back to trigonometry which made my brain hurt a little, but to make it simple, in this case you get it by doing : **translationDistance = (faceWidth/2) / tan(30)**.
See [this article](https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/) by *David DeSandro* for more explanations.
In my code :

```
--cotetriangle: 200px;
/* r = 100 / tan(30) = 57.7 */
--translationDistance: 58px;
```

The angle of rotation is easy, 3 faces, 360deg -> 120deg for each rotation.
Which gives you :

```
.triangle-face-front {
  background: rgb(71, 71, 136);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, var(--translationDistance));
}

.triangle-face-left {
  background: rgb(90, 233, 77);
  transform: rotateY(-120deg) translate3d(0, 0, var(--translationDistance));
}

.triangle-face-right {
  background: black;
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translate3d(0, 0, var(--translationDistance));
}
```

I did a little 'pausing' animation as you suggested :

```
@keyframes rotateTriangle {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  24%,34%{
    transform: rotateY(120deg);
  }
  58%,67%{
    transform: rotateY(240deg);
  }
  91%, 100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
```

To switch between a lateral rotation (code above) and a frontal rotation, you just need to replace `rotateY` by `rotateX` 
To understand better CSS 3D, I encourage you to read those 2 articles :

- [Intro to CSS 3D transforms](https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/) by David DeSandro
- [Creating a 3D Cube Image Gallery](https://css-tricks.com/creating-a-3d-cube-image-gallery/) by Kushagra Gour

Comment: thank you so much for taking time to help me out with my issue. Love your way of approach and way you gave a solution to my issue.